# Policy Based Routing Not Working Correctly

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I have a openVPN connected on my ubuntu computer but I would like to have a couple of applications run through my home router untunneled. They run on port 22 and 32400 (ssh and plex).

So I've done some research on how to set up policy specific routing.

The problem is that despite my best efforts it appears that everything still gets routed through the VPN

**Summary of What I've Done**

My `rp_filter` is set to 0. I modified my mangle table to add a mark to packets with destination port 32400 and 22. I have a rule to send the marked packets to the custom table "notunnel" and the default route for the notunnel table is my routers gateway.

(Please note I am using port 80 as a test port because it's easier to view my public ip through a website than to ssh into my home network to test the configuration).

**Here's are the tables**

```
user@host:~$ ip rule show
0:  from all lookup local 
32765:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup notunnel 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default

user@host:~$ ip route show table main
default via 10.158.1.5 dev tun0  proto static 
10.158.1.1 via 10.158.1.5 dev tun0  proto static 
10.158.1.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.158.1.6 
172.98.67.18 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.10  metric 9

user@host:~$ ip route show table notunnel
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 

user@host:~$ sudo iptables -t mangle -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED CONNMARK restore
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
CONNMARK   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http CONNMARK set 0x1
CONNMARK   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:32400 CONNMARK set 0x1
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             CONNMARK save
CONNMARK   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:32400 CONNMARK set 0x1
CONNMARK   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http CONNMARK set 0x1

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

So as always any advice will be welcomed with open arms.

Comment: You are marking the incoming packets, but not the reply packets?  Try marking the ones with `spt:http` and `spt:32400` (note that your description says port 22 but your config is port  80)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paul, I've added the spt80 and 32400 as you requested but to no avail. Also thank you for the heads up on the port error I was using port 80 for testing because it was easier to go to "whatismyipaddress.com" than to go outside my home network and try and ssh into my home computer so I decided to use port 80 for testing purposes.